# Cooja hello-world-example.csc simulator in instantcontiki 3.0 is giving comiplation error: attempt to use poisoned "SPMCR" in boot.h

Tags: contiki, cooja

Inside instantcontiki3.0 ubuntu, started cooja simulator using command to start cooja simulator.

ant run

from folder /home/user/contiki/tools/cooja

Below error is seen when hellow world simulation is started from cooja simulator using following steps.

"File->Open simulation->2 cooja_helloworld.csc"->Select hello-world-example.csc->Open

In file included from ../../cpu/avr/dev/flash.c:4:0:
/usr/lib/avr/include/avr/boot.h:128:16: error: attempt to use poisoned "SPMCR"

```
 #elif defined (SPMCR)
                ^
```

make: *** [obj_micaz/flash.o] Error 1

Below code is broken in instantcontiki3.0

```
/* Check for SPM Control Register in processor. */
#if defined (SPMCSR)
    #  define __SPM_REG    SPMCSR
#elif defined (SPMCR)
    #  define __SPM_REG    SPMCR
#else
    #  error AVR processor does not provide bootloader support!
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Change below code

```
/* Check for SPM Control Register in processor. */
#if defined (SPMCSR)
#  define __SPM_REG    SPMCSR
#elif defined (SPMCR)
#  define __SPM_REG    SPMCR
#else
#  error AVR processor does not provide bootloader support!
#endif
```

to

```
/* Check for SPM Control Register in processor. */
#if defined (SPMCSR)
#  define __SPM_REG    SPMCSR
//#elif defined (SPMCR)
//#  define __SPM_REG    SPMCR
#else
//#  error AVR processor does not provide bootloader support!
#  if defined (SPMCR)
#    define __SPM_REG    SPMCR
#  else
#    error AVR processor does not provide bootloader support!
#  endif 
#endif
```

inside /usr/lib/avr/include/avr/boot.h